# Automatic generation of database tables from Spring Roo

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-roo

I'm having trouble with something that I understand should function out of the box - I am not getting any tables generated in my MySQL database despite having made the following checks:

1. That the schema is already defined
2. That the persistence.xml file contains `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`
3. That the Entity class contains the `@RooJpaActiveRecord` annotation.

I'm using Hibernate and MySQL. I used the `persistence setup` command for this.
My questions:

A. Have I missed anything?

B. Is it imperative that I use the Roo command line for the initial definition of the entity? Is Roo clever enough to detect (when it is running) that I have used a Roo annotation, so it should 'kick in' and populate any further configuration that I require in order for the table to exist the next time I restart my server? (For balance, I've tried both creating a new Entity via the command line and by creating a new class / manually adding the annotation, and no dice...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that my Eclipse install had somehow reverted itself to Roo v1.5, which doesn't appear to support the JPA annotations.

Now running 1.2.0 without problems.

Hope this helps someone.